# User.Claims is null after deploying application while users are still logged in

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, claims-based-identity

I have a aspnet core web application that uses Identity claims (w/ JWT token authorization). I have the expiration for the token set for 2 days.

The normal process of logging in, authenticating credentials, and receiving / sending tokens works well.

The problem I'm having is **when I deploy the application to IIS AND users are still logged in, the User.Claims property is null**. The User object has no value. It only gets refreshed if they log out and then log back in.

The only idea I can think of is detecting if the claims are null and redirecting to login, but this isn't ideal as they may be continuing to update information from the day before, only to have it fail on submission.

EDIT (code sample):

```
            ApplicationUser appUser = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(login).Result;

            var displayName = appUser.ToDisplayName();

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims, "Bearer");
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("displayName", displayName));  

            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(appUser, new Claim("id", appUser.Id)); // server claim               
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(appUser, new Claim("displayName", displayName)); // server claim
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);

            // return token to client.
            var expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2880);
            var token = GetJwtToken(expires, claimsIdentity);

            return new TokenDTO()
            {
                id_token = token,
                tokenExpires = expires,
                displayName = displayName,
                authenticated = true,
                username = appUser.UserName,
                roles = applicationRoles // roles is for client-side nav authorization
            };
```

GetJwtToken

```
    private string GetJwtToken(DateTime? expires, ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(new 
     SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        {
            Issuer = _tokenOptions.Issuer,
            Audience = _tokenOptions.Audience,
            SigningCredentials = _tokenOptions.SigningCredentials,
            Subject = identity,
            Expires = expires,
            NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)
        });

        return handler.WriteToken(securityToken);
    }
```

**Calling User.Claims:**

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody]OrderProcessUpdateDTO 
     orderProcessUpdateDTO)
    {
          // claims is sometimes null here
          var currentUserId = User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == 
          nameof(CustomClaimType.id)).Value;

        ...

      }
```

Comment: I don't know how you are generating the JWT token, but in my case, my token has my important claims. Can you share some code?

Comment: Where do you call User.Claims? In a controller? Also, HttpContext.User.Claims is null? I always use HttpContext.User.Claims. I put everything in the claimsIdentity and i recreate my user object based on what is on HttpContext.User.Claims

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks. I just made an edit to show where I'm calling User.Claims. I'll try to use HttpContext as you recommended and see what the difference is. To muddy up the waters more, this seems like an intermittent problem that I can't always reproduce, so there may be something else not configured correctly. I'll test it out. BTW I'm using *<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.2" />* if that matters

Comment: Think it's not an entity framework problem. I don't know if is your case, but i have store the token in a cookie and using (IApplicationBuilder) app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication and app.UseCookieAuthentication with both AutomaticAuthenticate and AutomaticChallenge to true. Maybe is not related, maybe is :)

Comment: the solution that worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140581/5654221